# Dispatcher initialization failed with struts 2.3 jars

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

I am trying a simple struts2 application with struts2.3 jars but it is giving a dispatcher initialization error

2.3 Jars included are:

```
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-chain-1.2.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-digester-2.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.18.jar
ognl-3.0.4.jar
struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar
xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar
```

web.xml is

```
 <filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

struts.xml is:

```
<struts>

<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<package name="/abc"  extends="struts-default">

<!-- action declarations.... -->
<action name="login" class="actions.TestLogin">
<result name="success">/WEB-INF/results/success.jsp</result>
<result name="error">/WEB-INF/results/error.jsp</result>
</action>

</package>
</struts>
```

Exception stack is:

```
SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:295)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:431)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$5.create(ContainerBuilder.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$3.create(ContainerBuilder.java:93)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:487)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:574)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder.create(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.createBootstrapContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:293)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStackFactory.setContainer(OgnlValueStackFactory.java:85)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Javassist library is missing in classpath! Please add missed dependency!
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.<clinit>(OgnlRuntime.java:168)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.ClassPool
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.<clinit>(OgnlRuntime.java:165)
    ... 39 more
11 Jun, 2012 9:14:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter Struts2
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException - Class: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector
File: ContainerImpl.java
Method: inject
Line: 295 - com/opensymphony/xwork2/inject/ContainerImpl.java:295:-1
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:449)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:295)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:431)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$5.create(ContainerBuilder.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$3.create(ContainerBuilder.java:93)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:487)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:574)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder.create(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.createBootstrapContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:436)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:293)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStackFactory.setContainer(OgnlValueStackFactory.java:85)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Javassist library is missing in classpath! Please add missed dependency!
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.<clinit>(OgnlRuntime.java:168)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.ClassPool
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.<clinit>(OgnlRuntime.java:165)
    ... 39 more
11 Jun, 2012 9:14:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
11 Jun, 2012 9:14:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/Pr_StrutsLoginMap] startup failed due to previous errors
11 Jun, 2012 9:14:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/Pr_StrutsLoginMap] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@2d13981b]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@61672bbb]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
11 Jun, 2012 9:14:47 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
11 Jun, 2012 9:14:47 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
11 Jun, 2012 9:14:47 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/16  config=null
11 Jun, 2012 9:14:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4032 ms
```

I tried executing the same application using struts 2.0 jars with 
web.xml as

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

It is working file but with struts 2.3 jars it is giving an Exception
I am not able to figure out what is the problem.Please suggest what might be the problem

Thank u

Comment: Without seeing what the exception is it'll be hard to help

Comment: put the complete stack trace to help you. commonly the possible reasons of failure are missing jar on incorrect version of dependency jar.

Comment: (By "hard" Alex means "impossible".)

Comment: I have modified the question and added the exception stack that is occurring while executing the application. Can you please figure out the problem with it.

Comment: @NishitJain:`Javassist library is missing in classpath!`. this is what clearly mentioned in the error

Comment: A Good discussion on this can be found at http://www.coderanch.com/t/507085/Struts/Error-running-Struts-Application-Tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Maintain following version of jars in you lib. I think you won't face any problem

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-digester.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang-1.2.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.16.jar
javassist-3.7.ga.jar
ognl-3.0.jar
struts2-core-2.2.3.jar
xwork-core-2.2.1.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Buddy your error stack trace itself tells you what the issue is, see this line in the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Javassist library is missing in classpath! Please add missed dependency!
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.<clinit>(OgnlRuntime.java:168)
```

This means that the javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar (or something like this) file is missing. Add that file, try to run your app again and then seen what other errors it gives. Best of Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

this error arrise when some jar is missing . so 
i tested struts simple application using your provided jar 
same issue as u defined 
but after including these 4 necessary jars

```
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
javaassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
asm-3.3.jar
asm-commons-3.3.jar
```

issue resolved .

Comment: Same answer as in February, and a year ago February, and it was resolved through the comments from two years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: This type of response should be a comment, and not an answer.  It doesn't explain what, nor does it provide any insight for others looking to solve the problem.  Furthermore, this question was answered and resolved over two years ago, with the discovery that it was missing dependencies.