# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.ClassPool in WebSphere v9.0

Tags: java, websphere, javassist

How to fix the issue when running a Struts2 application in WebSphere v9.0 that results in the error below?
The same app runs in WebSphere v8.5.5 without the error.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Javassist library is missing in classpath! Please add missed dependency!
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.(OgnlRuntime.java:169)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.ClassPool

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11200082/6216002), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18539082/6216002) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10967528/6216002).

Comment: Maybe you should just add missing library to your application?